# Python response module using PUT with parameters

Tags: python, python-requests, url-parameters

I'm currently trying to use a RestAPI to set user permissions via a python script. It reads the permission from one server and has to import the permissions of a the same user on another server.
I am using the ***python requests*** module and did read up on how to use ***put*** with parameters but appear to have issues with the correct syntax.

[**RestAPI endpoint**](http://server:111/rest/api/1.0/projects/projectname/permissions/users?username&permission)

the username and permission part is what causes my issue.

I have tried like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests
payload = (({username}), ({permission}))
set_user_permission_project = requests.put(f'{url}/rest/api/1.0/projects/{row[2]}/permissions/users', auth=(user, pw), params=payload)
```

And prior to that attempt, I tried it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests
set_user_permission_project = requests.put(f'{url}/rest/api/1.0/projects/{row[2]}/permissions/users?{username}&{row[8]}', auth=(user, pw))
```

Probably I am missing something very essential here and don't get it.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help

Br

Comment: I can't help but notice you do not use a key+var structure in your parameters. Is there a reason why you don't apply common practices? The URL would be like this: ```http://server:111/rest/api/1.0/projects/projectname/permissions/users?username=usernamevalue&permission=permissionvalue```
Could you also clarify what issues you run into? What is your HTTP response? What is the result of your code, etc.

Comment: Dear @estherwn thanks for your comment. The RestAPI itself is coming from the hosted java application and it requires to provide the username after the ? which will get the permissions provided after the &
Does this make now more sense?

Comment: Alright, well then I do not see why your first attempt would not work. ( this one: ```set_user_permission_project = requests.put(f'{url}/rest/api/1.0/projects/{row[2]}/permissions/users?{username}&{row[8]}', auth=(user, pw))```) 
What is the response you received in this case?
In case you haven't done so already, it might prove valuable to print the URL in a log file, something like: 
```print(f'{url}/rest/api/1.0/projects/{row[2]}/permissions/users?{username}&{row[8]}')``` 
It could be interesting if you would be able to post to this URL using 'Postman' or a similar tool.

Comment: Your first comment regarding the structure of the parameters (key+value) was actually correct... Thank you very much for pointing it out. I checked once more on the RestAPI, which is provided by 3rd party, and did as you recommended... It is working now.
I checked beforehand the RestAPI with curl commands... My bad. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the very useful comments from @estherwn I double checked on the RestAPI and adapted the call accordingly. It was supposed to be key+var as suggested.
Hence the answer for me was:

`import requests
set_user_permission_project = requests.put(f'{url}/rest/api/1.0/projects/{row[2]}/permissions/users?name={username}&permission={row[8]}', auth=(user, pw))`

I hope someone will find this helpful one day.
Thanks once more for your help @estherwn